# How to nest a query in a postgres query

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to build a Postgres query (shown below) for the following requirement.

I have 2 tables, `member` and `booking`.  For each booking the member receives a rating (a rating can be between 1 to 5, 5 being the top score).  The output of this query is currently showing each member's overall score.

I now need to add the most recent booking that each member has but I'm not sure how!? :-(  This should be possible as the `booking` table has a column `time_starts` which I can use.  You can see my attempt below, I'm basically trying to add the following onto my existing query:

**Get the latest booking for each member**

```
SELECT time_starts from booking WHERE id = XYZ ORDER BY time_starts DESC LIMIT 1
```

**Query**

```
with member_ratings AS (                        
    select                  
        r.member_id,                
        sum(IsNull(r.rating, 0)) "total",               
        cast(count(*) * 5 as decimal) "possible_max",               
        cast(total/possible_max as decimal(10,2)) "score_as_percentage",                
        cast(5 * score_as_percentage as decimal(10,2)) "score"
    from review r
    join booking b on 'urn:booking:' || b.id = r.booking_urn        
    group by 1                  
)
SELECT *            
FROM member_ratings                     
where score < 4.8                       
order by score desc
```

**My attempt**

```
with member_ratings AS (                        
    select                  
        r.member_id,                
        sum(IsNull(r.rating, 0)) "total",               
        cast(count(*) * 5 as decimal) "possible_max",               
        cast(total/possible_max as decimal(10,2)) "score_as_percentage",                
        cast(5 * score_as_percentage as decimal(10,2)) "score",
        "most_recent" = SELECT time_starts from booking WHERE id = XYZ ORDER BY time_starts DESC LIMIT 1
    from review r
    join booking b on 'urn:booking:' || b.id = r.booking_urn        
    group by 1                  
)
SELECT *            
FROM member_ratings
```

Many thanks

**Query updates available here**

```
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=409abbd3519d30f6de63003752d7d9fb
```

Comment: Use `(SELECT …) AS "most recent"`. No equals sign. Just an expression before the alias. (Also, get a proper value instead of  `XYZ`)

Comment: Not sure how to replace XYZ?

Comment: Well, what id do you want to use for each subquery?

Comment: The query is returning members and their bookings.  Each booking has a rating.  But I also want to have the date of the last booking each member received.

Comment: so the subquery (to get the most recent booking) needs to be inside the "join booking b on 'urn:booking:' || b.id = r.booking_urn" filter..  My attempt I don't think can do that because it's outside the join and in the select (trying to explain this is pushing my sql knowledge)

Comment: Does this `cast(total/possible_max as decimal(10,2)) "score_as_percentage"` actually work? I didn't think you could reference columns created in the same select from expressions.

Comment: referencing columns from expressions seems to work

Comment: [Doesn't work for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=da757d51ccd32fcc6f35f0ec6453ef2f). Is there a trick I'm missing? Or maybe one of your `review` or `bookings` tables contain actual `total` and `possible_max` columns?

Comment: how strange, maybe I'm seeing false positives!  Let me confirm, should probably say I'm using Navicat Premium to build and execute the queries

Comment: I've updated the dbfiddle.uk link, can you see my update?  I assume you can, very strange as I can't get it working there

Comment: No, if you change a dbfiddle and submit (run) it, it'll generate a new url. You'd need to link that here in the comments.

Comment: I've updated my question with the link but it's here for convenience.  I've removed the select expressions into a separate table, and this works in dbfiddle -> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=409abbd3519d30f6de63003752d7d9fb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a subquery here. You're already selecting from the `booking` table, grouped by the member - all you need is an aggregate function giving you the last `time_starts` date in each group:

```
select
    r.member_id,
    sum(IsNull(r.rating, 0)) "total",
    cast(count(*) * 5 as decimal) "possible_max",
    cast(total/possible_max as decimal(10,2)) "score_as_percentage",
    cast(5 * score_as_percentage as decimal(10,2)) "score",
    max(b.time_starts) "most_recent"
from review r
join booking b on 'urn:booking:' || b.id = r.booking_urn
group by 1;
```

Comment: I'll do some testing but I think you're right, initial checks using your query it looks good